# Cannot solve Error Attribute Alpha not found

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle

My project in android studio has the following error

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml","position":{"startLine":19}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml","position":{"startLine":19}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml","position":{"startLine":18}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_default.xml","position":{"startLine":18}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_default.xml:19: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_edittext.xml","position":{"startLine":18}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_edittext.xml:19: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml","position":{"startLine":18}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_spinner.xml","position":{"startLine":18}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_spinner.xml:19: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_switch_track.xml","position":{"startLine":18}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_switch_track.xml","position":{"startLine":19}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_switch_track.xml","position":{"startLine":20}}],"original":"C:\\Users\\varun\\.gradle\\caches\\transforms-2\\files-2.1\\aaffe2c7f23d715ca045db9d0a51d031\\appcompat-v7-28.0.0\\res\\color\\abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21: AAPT: error: attribute alpha (aka com.arijit.viking:alpha) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
```

Since this a support library error and I cannot edit it I am stuck.
My build.gradle(:app)

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.arijit.viking"
        minSdkVersion 15

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'




}
configurations.all {
    exclude module: 'support-fragment'
    exclude module: 'support-core-ui'
    exclude module: 'support-compat'
    exclude module: 'loader'
    exclude module: 'localbroadcastmanager'
    exclude module: 'print'
    exclude module: 'documentfile'
    exclude module: 'collections'
    exclude module: 'cursoradapter'
    exclude module: 'support-core-utils'


}
```

Project level build.gradle

```
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

appcompat-v7-28.0.0\res\color\abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:state_enabled="false"
          app:alpha="?android:attr/disabledAlpha"
          android:color="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"/>
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent"/>
</selector>
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project
This was an existing project made in Eclipse and i have to run it in Android Studio

Any help will be appreciated

**EDIT #1:** After migrating the project to Androidx all the errors have been fixed however the built apk doesnt work at all. How do I check the issue?

Comment: move to androidx

Comment: try looking at ?android:attr/disabledAlpha maybe it has an invalid/deprecated value or something

Answer (score 2):

- Try Cleaning the project and the invalidate Cache/Restart.
- Remove attr: android:alpha="?android:disabledAlpha"
- Migrate to AndroidX

Comment: How do i remove attr: android:alpha="?android:disabledAlpha"? Its part of the external library and I am unable to change it

Comment: Immigrate to AndroidX then

Comment: That's very unhelpful since androidx.appcompat:appcompat:* is what uses alpha ‍♀️

Comment: Migrating to AndroidX is the best option.

Comment: AGAIN: this error occurs WITH androidx.appcompat:appcompat:*, which IS androidx. no?

Comment: No look at the dependencies: `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` it is not AndroidX. Although this question is old and I do not fully remember what happened here and you might have a different issue than the one here. The ultimate solution for this case is to migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I ran across this in a strange build setup today.

The library is looking for attribute 'alpha' in **OUR** APP resources.
In 'main/resources/dimen.xml' add an attribute:

```
<attr name="alpha">100</attr>
```

This will satisfy the reference in app-compat and you wont see any errors when processing resources.